# How can I use the same menu items in app-drawer and app-header?

Tags: polymer

The [transform navigation demo](https://polymerelements.github.io/app-layout/patterns/transform-navigation/) described in [responsive-navigation-pattern](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/app-layout#responsive-navigation-pattern) section of the Polymer documentation uses an `array` of `items` to build up a single menu that is used twice (in the `app-drawer` and in the `app-header`). See the source [here](https://github.com/polymerelements/app-layout/blob/master/patterns/transform-navigation/x-app.html).

A simplified example is shown below:

```
<app-drawer-layout>
  <app-drawer>
    <paper-menu>
      <!-- MENU ITEMS -->
    </paper-menu>
  </app-drawer>
  <app-header-layout>
    <app-header>
      <app-toolbar>
        <div main-title>App name</div>

        <paper-tabs>
          <!-- SAME MENU ITEMS HERE -->
        </paper-tabs>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>

    main content

  </app-header-layout>
</app-drawer-layout>
```

This is part of the script that initializes the menu items:

```
items: {
  type: Array,
  value: function() {
  return ['Item One', 'Item Two', 'Item Three', 'Item Four', 'Item Five'];
  }
}
```

**What would be a better way to initialize the menu only once without using an array?**

Defining the menu as a new `element` would be great but this will not work I guess because in the drawer these are `paper-menu` items and in the header these are `paper-tabs`.

Comment: I would just do an ordinary `dom-repeat` on your array and duplicate the code at both places. You could create a new element, that renders just the menu items, but this seems like an overkill for such a simple scenario.

Comment: @alesc Thank you but that is the same thing that the example shows and that is what I have now. I am looking for a different solution where I can list the menu items in an element an use that without duplicating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new element that will display an array of items.
Bind the data from **items** to your element attribute **display-items**.
You also should have an attribute to propagate the selected item.

```
<item-menu display-items=[[items]] selected-item={{selectedItem}}></item-menu>


<app-drawer-layout>
  <app-drawer>
    <paper-menu>
      <item-menu display-items=[[items]] selected-item={{selectedItem}}></item-menu>
    </paper-menu>
  </app-drawer>
  <app-header-layout>
    <app-header>
      <app-toolbar>
        <div main-title>App name</div>

        <paper-tabs>
          <item-menu display-items=[[items]] selected-item={{selectedItem}}></item-menu>
        </paper-tabs>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>

    main content

  </app-header-layout>
</app-drawer-layout>
```

Ps: This code only demonstrates how to propagate the value of the array items to multiple polymer elements. I assumed that you were familiar with creating new polymer element and importing them into your app.